# I need kernel headers for 2.6.21.5

Tags: kernel, slackware

Preferably in slackware module format(lzm). Can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [this could help you, some mirrors' `/linux/slackware/slackware-12.0/source/k/`](http://ftp.gwdg.de/linux/slackware/slackware-12.0/source/k/) that contains `linux-2.6.21.5.tar.bz2` **and** the SlackBuild files creating the different kernel variants Slackware uses.  (I basically searched for `"2.6.21.5"`.)